# Latex homework template

Tags: templates

[image]Does anyone know how to get or code this template and can u suggest some like this

Comment: a suggestion https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates?q=homework

Comment: This site (and Stack sites in general) does not work well as "please do this for me".  If you can narrow this down to a single specific feature (blue left border with text; blue boxes around exercises with number; green hexagons around parts of exercises) and show what you have so far, then we can better help you out.

Comment: At the page https://elmaths.com/امتحان-تجريبي-رقم-1-الثانية-باك-علوم-ر/ you could find below the image of the document a text which say that you can contact the authors to obtain the LaTeX source (email address provided on the same page). Suggest they to made the template of the document public :). For the blocks of exercices, they uses probably the package **tcolorbox**.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the authors comment to the first answer indicates a sufficient hint for now. There‘s quite some coding ahead for a novice to obtain a result like in the posted screenshot. So I expect little progress in detailing this question, and probably a few more detailed, focused and new questions in near future while approaching the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an exemple for an exercice block, with the package **tcolorbox**. See section 10 of the manual (about the *tcolorbox* library `skin`) and section 10.2.1 about the title placement.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
    title=Exercice 6, attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    boxed title style={size=small,colback=blue!25!white},
    colframe=blue,colback=white,coltitle=black]
La moitié du triple d'un nombre décimal est égal à 15,3. \textbf{Déterminer ce nombre.}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help